# Trouble repeating queries with different Parse object ID

Tags: ios, swift

I have a query that needs to access the data in a certain row on my Parse data controller.  Each row of data has a different object ID, and it seems I need to write a completely new function for each row of data.  For instance, here's the function:

```
    @IBAction func addVote1(sender: AnyObject) {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("BiEM17uUYT") {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            voteCount1.incrementKey("votes")
            voteCount1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
            let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
            let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
            self.pollResults1.text = "\(votes)"
        }

        }
    }
```

The thing is, I have another query that the button could call that is the exact same function and query only with a different ID in "getObjectInBackgroundWithId" as follows:

```
    @IBAction func addVote1(sender: AnyObject) {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("TtKGatVCi9") {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            voteCount1.incrementKey("votes")
            voteCount1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
            let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
            let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
            self.pollResults1.text = "\(votes)"
        }

        }
    }
```

How do I make it so that I only have to write that code once and just have it access the data with a random object ID?  I've tried this so far in my viewDidLoad method but have only gotten error messages:

```
        let array = ["BiEM17uUYT", "TtKGatVCi9"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    var objectId = array[randomIndex]

    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("objectId") {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            voteCount1.incrementKey("votes")
            voteCount1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
            let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
            let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
            self.pollResults1.text = "\(votes)"
        }
    }
```

What is it I'm doing wrong, and how do I just access a random objectId in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string with value "objectId" to `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` instead of the value of `objectId`.

Change:

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("objectId") {
```

to:

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectId) {
```

Comment: Did you try this?  If it doesn't work, what symptoms are you seeing?